# A tricky way of replacing insertion of a numpy array into another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want my inserted array to replace as many elements in the target array as there are in this replacing array, just like this:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([6, 7, 8])
# Doing unknown stuff
x = array([6, 7, 8, 4, 5])
```

Is there some numpy method or something tricky to implement this?

I would also like to know if this can be done despite of how the lengths of the arrays relate to each other, for instance like this:

```
x = np.array([1, 2])
y = np.array([6, 7, 8])
# Doing unknown stuff
x = array([6, 7])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution

```
x[:len(y)] = y[:len(x)]
```

First case

```
>>> x
array([6, 7, 8, 4, 5])
```

Second case

```
>>> x
array([6, 7])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not the same"? The memory address of `x` will not be modified only the replaced cells.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

```
x = np.append(y, x[len(y):])
```

Comment: Thanks, still please check out the second question I have appended

Answer (score 2):

Numpy is relatively fast:

```
   x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
   y = np.array([6, 7, 8])
   xnew = np.concatenate((y, x[len(y):]))
```

```
>>> xnew
array([6, 7, 8, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Thanks, yet the question has been updated